# TFS 2015 Gated Checkin Build Issue

Tags: tfs, gated-checkin

I am having and issue with TFS 2015 doing a continuous integration build. I have added 3 projects to my Questionnaires solution which are meant to be shared code between other solutions as well. Therefore those projects each have their own folder structures under TFS not under Questionnaires.

When I go to do a checkin, TFS is getting the path wrong to one of the projects and therefore won't build. The path it is looking for is-

C:\Builds\1\Questionnaires\Questionnaires\src\Source2\Questionnaires\Dev\Questionnaires\Questionnaires.sln.metaproj: The project file "C:\Builds\1\Questionnaires\Questionnaires\src\Source2\Questionnaires\Dev\Questionnaires......\Common\Main\Common\Common.Utilities\Common.Utilities.csproj" was not found.

That should be the correct path as that is the way it is in TFS under it's own folder.

Where the code is actually ending up is:

C:\Builds\1\Questionnaires\Questionnaires\src\Source2\Common

the \Main\Common folder is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your workspace mapping under the "source settings" tab. This sets the folders that will be downloaded from source control to your build server's working folder for the build.

Comment: Could you give me a bit more information? I don't know where to find the source settings tab. Thanks for getting me started though.

Comment: Right click on the build definition, click "Edit build definition".